# How to create a nested list from another list?

Tags: python, list

`list1=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`

I want to create a list `[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]` from `list1`.
I tried `list(list1)` but it's showing only `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` instead of `[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]`.

Comment: If you ask a question about lists, it's usually implied that numpy isn't a necessity to solve the problem... just a heads up. Also please don't use the tag `arrays` if you're talking about `list`s.

Comment: `list([list1])` does it for me.

Comment: what about `[list1]` ?

Comment: Think carefully about the logic. How many elements should the new list contain? (Hint: One.) What should the first element be? (Hint: `list1`.) How do you write code that means "a list with one element, where that element is `list1`"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just initialise a new `list` which has a `sub-list` that is `list1`.

This is done with:

```
[list1]
```

which will give:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
```

Or alternatively, when you are defining `list1`, you can *define* it already `nested` inside another `list`:

```
list1 = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
```

---

Note that when you were trying to `nest` the original `list` inside another `list`, using `list()` will not work.

If you read [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list):

> The constructor builds a list whose items are the same and in the same order as iterable’s items. iterable may be either a sequence, a container that supports iteration, or an iterator object. If iterable is already a list, a copy is made and returned, similar to iterable[:]. For example, list('abc') returns ['a', 'b', 'c'] and list( (1, 2, 3) ) returns [1, 2, 3]. If no argument is given, the constructor creates a new empty list, [].

The key thing mentioned here is that `list` creates a `list` from an `iterable`. As `list1` is a `list` already, it is an `iterable`. This means that the `list()` constructor will treat as an `iterable` and create a new `list` from the `elements` inside `list1` - creating a copy of it. So that is why it wasn't working as you expected it to.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to put it in another list using. When you declare a list, you put them in two square brackets. If you want to make a list of lists, you'll have to use them twice.

```
lis = [your_list]
```

Comment: `list()` is redundant

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried?

```
list2 = [list1]
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
list1=list([list1])
```

Answer (score 0):

One line solution :

```
list1=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

print([[nested_list for nested_list in list1]])
```

or just use:

```
list1=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

nested_list=[list1]
```